# CSS to border <tr> entirely doesn't work properly in Internet Explorer

Tags: css

I'm using the following CSS to border a `<tr>` entirely.

```
<style type="text/css">
    tr.top td { border-top: thin solid black; }
    tr.bottom td { border-bottom: thin solid black; }
    tr.row td:first-child { border-left: thin solid black; }
    tr.row td:last-child { border-right: thin solid black; }
</style>
```

It works perfectly in Mozilla Firefox but in Internet Explorer, it doesn't border the last right `<td>` as shown in the following snap shots.

In Firefox, it displays the following table.

[image]

In Internet Explorer(8) however, it displays the table as follows.

[image]

Means that in the above CSS, this CSS class `tr.row td:last-child { border-right: thin solid black; }` doesn't work in IE. What is the solution to this? I'm using IE 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE 8 doesn't support the `:last-child` pseudo class (CSS 3), but it does support `:first-child` (CSS 2.1)

[CSS Compatibility and Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You'll need a different selector for the last cell such as a custom class name.

Comment: +1, and a further reference from [`last-child` compatibility, at Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t35).

Comment: Done with a custom CSS class as you say.

Answer (score 1):

btw, what if you declare the border out of the css file, but instead after style, within the TD tag? I was told that IE8 has some bugs with border rendering. Post it here, and see if it works.

another doubt, why don't you use 1px instead of thin!?